# SQLite conflict resolution not working

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have an SQLite database containing 3 tables.

I am trying to insert a row into one of them with a primary key that already exists. The primary key is of type integer.

This statement should fail because of a constraint violation. In my c# program it is not failing, but it is not inserting anything either. So basically it's working like if I started the statement with `insert or ignore`. If I use `insert or fail` explicitly it still does not work. This also happens when opening the database from the SQLite manager firefox plugin. However if I open the database in Sqliteman the query fails as it's supposed to.

Is there a pragma or something that I may have missed?

Edit: Here is the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE block(offset integer primary key,length integer,originaloffset integer,originalLength integer,page integer)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX block_original_offset_index on block(originaloffset,offset,length)
```

Comment: There's certainly a pragma for foreign key enforcement; I wonder if that's relevant…

Comment: And what exactly is the table definition?

Comment: I already tried enabling foreign keys but it made no difference. I'm not using any foreign keys in my database though. Just 3 simple tables with 4 or 5 columns each